# Unable to display continuous output from a python script to HTML view in django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to display the continuous output from a python script on the HTML page but the output is being displayed once the entire execution of the script is completed. I have used subprocess to run the python script(test.py) and when I execute the python script independently I could see the output line by line but the same is not working when I use it along with websockets. Can anyone please help me fix the problem?

Here is my code:

**consumers.py**

```py
import os
import subprocess
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class MyAsyncWebsocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("Websocket connected")
        print("Channel name...", self.channel_name)
        print("Channel layer...", self.channel_layer)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('programmers', self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        print("Message received from the client", text_data)
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        script = current_dir + '/' + 'test.py'
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python', script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=3)
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                line = line.decode("utf-8").strip()
                await self.send(text_data=line)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e)

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        print("Websocket disconnected", code)
```

**index.html**

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h3>Count Page</h3>
   <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20">

  </textarea><br>

   <input type="button" value="Submit" id="script-run-submit">


   <script>
       var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/awsc/')

        ws.onopen = function() {
            console.log("Websocket connection opened")
        }

        ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("Message received from the server", event)
            data = event['data']
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data + '\n')
        }

        ws.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("Websocket error occurred", event)
        }

         ws.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log("Websocket connection close", event)
        }

        document.getElementById('script-run-submit').onclick = function (event) {
               console.log("This function is executed")
               ws.send(JSON.stringify({ 'msg' : 'Trigger the script' }))
       }

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Expectation**

The script output should be displayed line by line in the HTML page

**Actual output**

All the output of the script is displayed at once in the HTML page